# Filter out blue light in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

Is there a way to change the display from an iOS app to filter out the blue light?

There is a f.lux app, but it is only available through cydia, so I figured iOS might not give regular apps the power to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean globally, then no. That's the reason F.lux is only available through Cydia as you mentioned.

If you mean only for your own app then you could simply tint all graphical elements in a more yellow tint though some clever tricks.

Comment: Ah, yes I mean globally, to bad it uses protected API levels.

Comment: @Rick do you know if this is possible via a desktop app? F.lux does it on MacOS and I'm trying to recreate it but am not finding much info to start on (am also new to Swift, but not development).